# Change VPN in Windows 7 from command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vpn

How can I change my VPN connection settings in Windows 7 from the command line?  I know how to do it using the GUI but I really need to do it from the console.

I need to change the user, password and internet address and then restart the connection. It doesn't matter if I have to install some third-party software in order to do this (from the command line).

Comment: What sort?  PPTP?

Comment: Ups... yes, PPTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it with the **rasdial** command

```
rasdial /disconnect
rasdial connection_name user pass /phone:host.example.com
```

Source: [Microsoft resources](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rasdial.mspx?mfr=true) and [some guy](http://www.s-code.com/forum/Topic704.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I have not got a PPTP connection set up to test this at the moment, but you could try making two connections in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\`.  The default connection is `rasphone.pbk`.

You could just execute them using the full path from the commmand line, but I am not sure if the first one automatically disconnects when you use the second one, as I cannot test it.

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction but it was not an accurate solution for my problem.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos: That's okay - I didn't expect it to be.