# Connect to L2TP/IPsec (username/password/PSK) on cmd.exe

Tags: cmd.exe, ipsec, l2tp

How may I connect to VPN using the username, password and PSK combo in the command line? Google has been of no help; any guidance will be most welcome.

I want a command to the effect of `vpnclient /server domain.tld /username u /password p /psk k` if at all possible. (I want to run it as part of a script on multiple systems)

Comment: If you're happy to use PowerShell, [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554820%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) page might be useful.

Comment: Otherwise, it looks like `rasdial` is the legacy command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change VPN in Windows 7 from command line](http://superuser.com/questions/412218/change-vpn-in-windows-7-from-command-line)

Comment: Further reading: http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2011/05/19/automate-creation-of-an-l2tp-vpn-with-pre-shared-key-and-automatically-use-windows-credentials/, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2555, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614465/establish-a-vpn-connection-in-cmd

Comment: @Bob I want a command to the effect of `vpnclient /server domain.tld /username u /password p /psk k` if at all possible. (I want to run it as part of a script on multiple systems) Would you happen to know any commands that'll let me do so?

Comment: That's basically what `rasdial` does, albeit with an existing connection. Something like `rasdial entryname username password` - you might be able to create a portable [`pbk` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specify it with `/phonebook:phonebookfile`. As for PSK... read the further reading links. You might be able to add it to the phonebook file. You can probably create the entry with the GUI and copy it from `%AppData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`

Comment: @Bob, if you'll put those step-by-step in an answer, I'll accept it. But do add opening the `pbk` file and adding the PSK to the already present line. It isn't saved by default for some reason.